# Getting all open files for process results in errno 12 = Out of Memory

Tags: swift, errno, lsof

With the help of SO, I wrote an app that displays all open TCP/UDP connections in Swift.
In the next step, I would like to get the process that opened the connection (pretty much as lsof does).

Since lsof is open source, I could write the following code to get all the open files for a process:

Bridging-Header:

```
#include <mach/mach_types.h>
#include <mach/vm_param.h>
#include <mach/host_info.h>
#include <mach/task_info.h>
#include <mach/thread_info.h>
#include <mach/vm_region.h>
#include <libproc.h>

#include <sys/proc_info.h>
#include <sys/kdebug.h>
#include <sys/msgbuf.h>
```

(I don't think every include is needed, but at least it compiles for now).

```
for app in NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications
    {
        let pid = app.processIdentifier

        var tai = proc_taskallinfo()
        let size = MemoryLayout<proc_bsdinfo>.size
        var result = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDTASKALLINFO, 0, &tai, Int32(size))
        let fileCount: Int32 = Int32(tai.pbsd.pbi_nfiles)

        if result <= 0
        {
            if errno == ENOMEM
            {
                Swift.print("Out of memory.")
            }
            Swift.print(errno)
            continue
        }

        var fid = proc_fdinfo()
        let fdInfoSize = MemoryLayout<proc_fdinfo>.size
        result = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, &fid, Int32(fdInfoSize) * fileCount)

        if result <= 0
        {
            Swift.print("Error. No Files?")
        }
        else
        {
            Swift.print("Files found.")
        }
    }
```

The code was ported from C to Swift 3. The original C code looks like this:

```
int nb;
struct proc_taskallinfo tai;
...  
nb = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDTASKALLINFO, 0, &tai, sizeof(tai));
```

When I run my code, I get the errno 12 (Out of memory). Why?

P.S. I know that the second proc_pidinfo will also fail because a pointer to an array of proc_fdinfo is returned and not a pointer to a single struct, but one step at a time. It's all about the errno 12.

Comment: Using C functions from your code does not qualify for the C tag.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `let size = MemoryLayout<proc_taskallinfo>.size` ? Where does the `proc_bsdinfo` come from?

Comment: Yes. Yes it should be....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors. First, it should be

```
let size = MemoryLayout<proc_taskallinfo>.size
```

Second, the `proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, ...)` expects a buffer
with room for `fileCount` structures of type `proc_fdinfo`, not just
a single one:

```
var fid = Array(repeating: proc_fdinfo(), count: Int(fileCount))
let fdInfoSize = MemoryLayout<proc_fdinfo>.stride
result = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, &fid, Int32(fdInfoSize) * fileCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code to get the TCP sockets. Unfortunately it is not possible to use the code in sandboxed apps:

```
for app in NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications {
    let pid = app.processIdentifier

    var tai = proc_taskallinfo()
    let size = MemoryLayout<proc_taskallinfo>.size
    var result = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDTASKALLINFO, 0, &tai, Int32(size))
    let fileCount: Int32 = Int32(tai.pbsd.pbi_nfiles)

    if result <= 0 {
        continue
    }

    var fid = Array(repeating: proc_fdinfo(), count: Int(fileCount))
    let fdInfoSize = MemoryLayout<proc_fdinfo>.stride
    result = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, &fid, Int32(fdInfoSize) * fileCount)

    if result <= 0 {
        Swift.print("Error PROC_PIDLISTFDS.")
    }
    else {
        for i in 0.. < Int(result) / fdInfoSize {
            let fdp = fid[i]

            if fdp.proc_fdtype == UInt32(PROX_FDTYPE_SOCKET) {
                var si = socket_fdinfo()
                let sizeSi = MemoryLayout<socket_fdinfo>.size
                result = proc_pidfdinfo(pid, fdp.proc_fd, PROC_PIDFDSOCKETINFO, &si, Int32(sizeSi))

                if result <= 0 {
                    Swift.print("Error PROC_PIDFDSOCKETINFO: " + errno.description)
                }
                else {
                    if si.psi.soi_kind == Int32(SOCKINFO_TCP) {
                        Swift.print("TCP Socket")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that `for i in 0.. < fdInfoSize` should be `for i in 0 ..< Int(result)/fdInfoSize`